# How to update "Area Path" of a test case in Azure Devops using Azure Devops Services Rest API

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, specflow

I write test cases in Visual Studio - Specflow feature file. Post that, I use "AzureDevops Test Connector" to migrate test cases into Azure Devops - Test Plan -> Test Suite(Which are already created in Azure Devops by me).

***My requirement is to update, "Area Path" and "Iteration" for the newly created test cases.***

I am able to update "Area Path" and "Iteration" for Test Plan and Test suite using Azure Devops Services Rest APIs. But, there is no provision to update these values in Test Case. Any lead will be much appreciated. Below is what i tried. Thanks in advance!

.

*PATCH CALL TO UPDATE AREA PATH AND ITERATION PATH - BUT IT IS NOT WORKING | SCREENSHOT FROM POSTMAN*

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by using "work item" instead of "Test Case". Using this, I am able to update all the field values.

Postman - add Content-Type = application/json-patch+json | under headers separately. Keep body as "raw" and "JSON" in drop down.

[Azure Devops Work Items Rest API Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#update-a-field)

[image]